# JDO - Do I need to call DetachCopy on my model object before passing it to a view?

Tags: java, jdo

My understanding of detach copy is that it makes a copy of your object so that you can make changes to it without the PersistenceManager noticing.

Since I close my PersistenceManager before passing the model object to the view to be used, I wouldn't have to call anything like detachCopy or makeTransient before passing it along would I?

The examples I looked at do call it though...
This is the example I looked at from http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html:

```
public Employee getEmployee(User user) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Employee employee, detached = null;
    try {
        employee = pm.getObjectById(Employee.class,
            "Alfred.Smith@example.com");

        // If you're using transactions, you can call
        // pm.setDetachAllOnCommit(true) before committing to automatically
        // detach all objects without calls to detachCopy or detachCopyAll.
        detached = pm.detachCopy(employee);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return detached;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have objects detached automatically using the PMF prop, or detach copies of them manually, as the example says. Now what was the question?

Comment: So it will throw an exception if I don't either detachCopy or makeTransient on it before closing the PM?

Comment: what will throw an exception ? If you dont makeTransient, or detachCopy or have that PMF prop set then the objects migrate to HOLLOW state, as per the JDO spec.

Comment: As per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/object_lifecycle.html

Comment: I think what Kyle was asking is, how will we be punished if we just return employee instead of pm.detachCopy(employee). What evil side affects are we avoiding by doing this?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the object after. Want the values of all fields present? Want to update it and repersist it? i.e define the full problem

Answer (score 1):

From http://db.apache.org/jdo/attach_detach.html

> *A detached object retains the id of its datastore entity. Detached
>   objects should be used where you want to update the objects and attach
>   them later (updating the associated object in the datastore. If you
>   want to create copies of the objects in the datastore with their own
>   identities you should use makeTransient instead of detachCopy.*